# how to make wordpress Theme options ajax based

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to make word press theme options ajax based ?
in word-press ,storing theme options refreshes the page , i want to make it ajax based . The problem i am facing is , there is no code for add_option or update_option ,how can i make it ajax based thanks

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are reinventing the wheel?, there are lots of stuff for this

1. [Redux Framework](https://reduxframework.com/)
2. [Options Framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/)
3. [Titan Framework](http://www.titanframework.net/)

There are many mores you can find on the internet. But if you really want to make on your on ajax theme options then you need to use [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
    var fruit = 'Banana';

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'example_ajax_request',
            'fruit' : fruit
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });   

});
```

**PHP**

```
function example_ajax_request() {

    // The $_REQUEST contains all the data sent via ajax 
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {

        $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];

        // Let's take the data that was sent and do something with it
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) {
            $fruit = 'Apple';
        }

        // Now we'll return it to the javascript function
        // Anything outputted will be returned in the response
        echo $fruit;

        // If you're debugging, it might be useful to see what was sent in the $_REQUEST
        // print_r($_REQUEST);

    }

    // Always die in functions echoing ajax content
   die();
}
```

More explanation on ajax you can find it [here](http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/)

Comment: $(document).on("submit", "form[action='options.php']", function(event) { 
   var btn = $(document.activeElement);
   name =  btn.attr("name");
   if(name == "update")
   {
   event.preventDefault();
   var settings =  $(this).serialize();
   $.post( 'options.php', settings ).error( 
    function() {
     alert('error');
    }).success( function() {
     alert('options saved successfully');   
    });
    return false; 
   }
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
This worked for me 

$(document).on("submit", "form[action='options.php']", function(event) { 
         var btn = $(document.activeElement);
         name =  btn.attr("name");
         if(name == "update")
         {
            event.preventDefault();
            var settings =  $(this).serialize();
            $.post( 'options.php', settings ).error( 
                function() {
                    alert('error');
                }).success( function() {
                    alert('options saved successfully');   
                });
                return false; 
         }
    });
```